# Am I using BeginSheet right? (MonoMac)

Tags: cocoa, monomac, cocoa-sheet

I have a feeling that I've either stumbled upon a bug (unlikely) or that I'm just using this function wrong (probably). I'm trying to make a sheet appear on my MainWindow. For some reason though, the sheet window pops up as a regular window without a toolbar and is in no way connected to my MainWindow at all.

Now I'm pretty new to cocoa and MonoMac so you'll have to forgive me, anyways, heres the code:

```
        TvShowSheetController sheet = new TvShowSheetController ();
        NSApplication.SharedApplication.BeginSheet (sheet.Window, Window);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha! Setting my sheet's window property "Visible at Launch" to false solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that Window is the window you wish to attach the sheet to?

An example from my code using an NSAlert:

```
alert = new NSAlert ();

alert.AddButton ("OK");
alert.MessageText = "Message";
alert.InformativeText = "Informative.";

alert.BeginSheet (Window, delegate {
    alert.Dispose ();
    alert = null;
});
```

Comment: Ok, this code works (altough I get a horrible amount of warnings about leaks :S). How can i get this working using a window instead of alert?

Comment: If you're getting leaks, you're doing work on a background thread with NSObjects without a NSAutoreleasePool.  Wrap your code in using (var pool = new NSAutoReleasePool ()) {}.  However, you should never be modifying the UI on any thread that isn't the main thread.

Comment: As far as I know I'm not running any background thread with NSObjects, unless BeginSheet starts one?